# Which is the correct method for outlier analysis on a dataset for modelling?

Tags: machine-learning, python, outliers, data-preprocessing

I'm trying to build a regression model but my data-set have many outliers points which I need to analyze and then remove them.

There are two ways to do it,

1) First do all the analysis on every feature without removing anything and then finally remove them at last based on the condition we got from doing the analysis.

2) Do analysis on first feature then remove outliers, then do analysis on second feature then remove outliers.... In this manner one after other.

The insights gained from first method differs from second method.

Which is the correct way?

Comment: The fact that you used the tag of outliers implies that you should be aware of the many threads with that tag. It's hard to see a new question here beyond your statement that you "need" to remove outliers and that there are precisely two ways to proceed. Much (my impression is most) statistical literature disputes the first and even those who agree with your latter statement would be hard pushed to explain that one is correct and the other is incorrect. I recommend studying some of the most highly upvoted threads on outliers,

Comment: This is a broad question.There are at least four distinct kinds of "outliers" in regression: (1) responses that are far from what would be predicted based on most of the remaining data; (2) observations where the explanatory variables are geometrically far from most of the others and (2a) the fit is sensitive to the explanatory values or (2b) the fit is not sensitive; (3) the data point is geometrically far from most data points but does not satisfy either of (1) or (2). The detection, treatment, and response to these four conditions vary--and depend on your objectives and fitting method.

Comment: In light of this, could you provide information that would help us distinguish what situation you are in?

Comment: @whuber I'm doing this analysis on NYC yellow taxi data for 2015. And first I've removed pickup locations and dropoff locations outside NYC city boundaries using latitudes and longitudes. So I'm wondering which method I should choose first or second? Both seems to giving different statistical results. I'm confused.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks I've read many but couldn't find any mention about this doubt I had. So the second is better compared to first right? Both methods seems to giving different statistical results. I'm confused about that.

Comment: Removing data for outside NYC is your aim is to study NYC isn't removal of outliers; it's just removal of data irrelevant to your purpose.

Comment: If you want me to choose, both methods you mentioned are wrong without a specific rationale. @Peter Flom's answer says more.

Comment: It's crucial to distinguish *outlier analysis* from *automatic outlier removal.*  The former is always a good thing to do to understand data, while the latter is virtually guaranteed to generate strong criticism of the results.  But as @Nick notes, this might not even be an outlier problem, but simply a matter of clarifying your definition of what population you're studying and selecting appropriate data for the purpose.

Comment: @whuber Not my problem is a outlier problem. I just don't know how to proceed with outlier analysis. Should I go with method 1 and remove outliers based on the statistical results I get. But I feel method 2 is more correct.

Comment: @NickCox No my problem is outlier removal not removing data irrelevant to my purpose. What do you mean by specific rationale? I just want to study each feature analyse their distribution, checking quantiles using box plot and then remove outliers. This is the second method I've mentioned. Is it correct? or should I use method1? Peter Flom's answer isn't much helpful. It doesn't say why.

Comment: You have to a good reason to remove outliers. You have not indicated any such, from which I guess that should not do it. You won’t get good advice for your project when you give so few details on what you’re doing.

Comment: You’re repeating your original question without really addressing any of the points or requests raised in discussion. No one who has reacted to date appears to accept your presumptions that must choose as you state.

Comment: @NickCox Every comment is kinda confusing. I can't seem to understand it properly. I have my data and there are many error data points (i.e some prices are very high(in millions which is wrong), some distance are very very large (which is also wrong)) these are wrong so I need to do such analysis using box plot etc.. on each feature independently and remove outliers right? I hope you get what I'm referring to her. At-least tell me what I need to provide further.

Comment: It's agreed that impossible values that you can't correct should be deleted, but telling the impossible and the merely implausible apart can be a hard task. Box plots are oversold here in my view; I'd use quantile plots and scatter plot matrices. Occasionally you can find a story: someone really did take a fare to Albany or Cleveland, or whatever, and the distance and the price align. That kind of issue is substantive rather than narrowly statistical.

Answer (score 3):

I would say neither is correct and that removing outliers based solely on statistical results is not a good idea. Rather than this, I suggest using a model that accommodates outliers. Since you are doing regression, two good models are robust regression (actually, that's a whole family of methods) or quantile regression.

Comment: But almost every data-analysis notebooks I've seen every one of them included outlier analysis based on statistical results. If I were to perform it what would be the correct method? First or Second or Any other? Also are there any implementation of robust regression and quantile regression available in scikit learn of any other python library?

Comment: I don't think either is correct.  You can look for outliers and then delete them if they are bad data (like a data entry error) but otherwise, it's a bad idea. There's lots of bad data analysis out there. That doesn't mean you should duplicate it.

I don't know Python at all, these tools are available in R and SAS .... I'm guessing they are in Python as well.

Comment: Outliers can also influence the results of quantile regression.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement Yes, but a) Much less than for OLS b) Only for certain quantiles (unless there are a LOT of outliers) and c) Some influence is probably appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterFlom, for your nice clarification.